# 'User' object has no attribute 'UserProfile'

Tags: django

I tried following the example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model on how to extend the user model. But I cannot retrieve the model data which I attached to the User.

model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ip = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

getting my User object

```
user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
g = user.UserProfile.ip
print(g)
```

The user gets fetched properly, and I'm able to get all the data that are with the standard user. But user.UserProfile will result in:

```
Internal Server Error: /Crowd/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\Crowd\src\Cr\views.py", line 35, in login
    g = user.UserProfile.ip
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'UserProfile'
[05/Sep/2016 04:32:46] "POST /Crowd/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 69185
```

I checked my database and I can see that there's a row in UserProfile which has a relation with User. So UserProfile is getting created properly(I assume).

Comment: try `user.userprofile.ip` not `user.UserProfile.ip`

Comment: @elethan wow, that was it. Wierd !

Comment: @vandelay, it may seem weird at first, but this is just the way Django's ORM defines relationships. See the docs that I link in my answer for more information.

Answer (score 6):

You should access the user profile of `user` with `user.userprofile`, not `user.UserProfile`. Try looking through [the docs for one-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/). It should make things much clearer as to how Django expects you to use such relationships.

Note also, that from the `UserProfile` side, you can access `User` with `.user` *not* `.User`. You will see that this is naming convention is always used with relationships in Django. Similarly, by default your tables in your database will be named something like `myapp_userprofile` rather than `myapp_UserProfile`.

Answer (score 0):

use `models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='userprofile')`
and add `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'app.UserProfile'`

in your `UserProfile` Class